# Progess dialog while loading datas from internet

Tags: android, progressdialog

How do i make ProgressDialog that will show while my method doing a bit while job? I know there's a lot related question to this but i don't understand the answers.
A separate thread is a good approach or not?
My method is downloading some datas from the Internet

Please provide me a quite detailed answer of how do i make this. 
A separate class will be great

Any answer and comment will be appriciated

Comment: a little research before asking, if you don't mind?

Comment: alright how do i delete my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey try the following code it may helpful :

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

new TheTask().execute();
 }

private class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

 @Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(YOUR_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    authenticate(); // method that calls the API via SOAP
    authenticateReal(); // method that handles the response
    return null;
}

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String str)
 {
    // Dismiss the dialog once finished
    pDialog.dismiss();  
  }
 }
```

Define pDialog before you call it:

```
   ProgresDialog pDialog;
```

Comment: where do i put the things that i will do in long time?

Comment: if i create a seperate class puting the code above how do i implement it? sorry for noobish question

Comment: instantiate it then after, call doinbackground like that?

Comment: Do your stuff in doInBackground() , you can refer this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog`